# XHR2 withCredentials - which cookies are sent?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, xmlhttprequest, credentials

Hopefully this is simple to answer.

With a credentialed request in XHR2, which cookies are sent?

I've been following [the MDN article on credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials), and it shows that the cookie `pageAccess=2` is sent with the request. However it doesn't explain where that cookie comes from, and why that cookie specifically is being sent. Is it simply that all cookies set by the page are sent in any credentialed request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the HTML5 Rocks page on [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-withcredentials):

> The `.withCredentials` property will include any cookies from the remote domain in the request, and it will also set any cookies from the remote domain.

I assume "any cookies" means "all cookies" (probably subject to a HTTPS-only flag on the cookie), since there is no mechanism to specify cookies with XHR2.

The cookies that get sent are the cookies that were set *by the remote domain*: if `foo.com` sends a request a credentialed request to `bar.com`, any cookies set by `bar.com` are sent. To put this in practical terms, suppose `facebook.com` has a CORS-aware API that requires you to be logged in to use. I've logged in to Facebook earlier in my browser session, but now I'm browsing `foo.com`, which is going to use Facebook's API on my behalf. `foo.com` asks th ebrowser to send a cross-domain request to `facebook.com` *along with all my `facebook.com` cookies* so Facebook knows who I am and that I've already authenticated to Facebook.

Comment: Ah - not sure how I missed that. I did read the HTML5Rocks page on this. Thanks a lot.