# How do I trigger the browser's Basic Authentication dialog from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, basic-authentication, wcf-security

I'm using basic authentication to secure a set of WCF web services exposed only inside our corporate network, and I was wondering if there was a way to trigger the browser's credentials dialog to appear from an AJAX call when the web service returns with a 401 error?

Currently my AJAX call receives the 401 as a regular failed request and doesn't prompt the browser to do anything. However, if I take the same URI and copy-paste it into into the browser's URL bar, the returned 401 correctly triggers the Basic Authentication dialog.

Is there any way to get the AJAX callback to tell the browser to pop up that dialog?

Comment: it should pop-up automatically if needed, even from the invisible ajax code. you probably need a more-specific ajax error handler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamically create an iframe with your url and append to document. It'll trigger authentication form. jQuery snipet to add iframe

```
$('<iframe src="your_url"></iframe>').appendTo('body')
```

A very simplified example is here:

```
var url = 'your_url_here';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    error: function(response){
        if(response.status==401){           
            $('<iframe src="'+url+'"></iframe>').appendTo('body');          
        }
    },
    success:function(){
        //your success code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to possibly manage the context here a little better? Perhaps to get the data passed in the iframe and push it back to the success function? I'd rather keep the iframe invisible.

Comment: Maybe also support POST methods as well?

Comment: @jab if you make iframe invisible browser may not make any request hence no authentication dialog. better make it 1x1 px or use absolute position for it and use very large top & left to make it disapear from document view port.

one way to push data to success function from iframe is by making the success function globally accessible and call it from iframe like **window.top.success(data)**

Answer (score 3):

I have faced almost the same 401 problem, except for my request was cross domain. But I hope the reason is the same. Following the instructions on [developer.mozilla - Access control CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) I have finally succeeded with simple:

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.open("GET", "https://my.foo.server/app/resource", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I think the `xhttp.withCredentials` is the solution. It is not header! You let browser to communicate with server through cookies. The following answer explains a lot [XHR2 withCredentials - which cookies are sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954184/355581)

Without `xhttp.withCredentials` there was always `401 (Unauthorized)`. But using it, the browser added the required header `Authorization:Basic dGVFooFooFooFoosaWVudA==` or **triggered the login dialog**, when credentials were not available yet.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and this answer led me straight to the analogous `withCredentials` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you'll need to provide the request with the credentials.

See [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: it is not answer its just suggetion use comment for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can invoke it from AJAX. Just pass the request with the following header:

`withCredentials: true`

Answer (score 1):

You would suggest to open/display/insert a form to allow inserting username and password and than resend the AJAX Request with the given credentials. I wouldn't really on browsers credential popup.

How you set authentication header you can read here: [How to use Basic Auth with jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

As found somewhere in the stack :

> Receiving a 401 response is the server telling you, “you aren’t
>   authenticated–either not authenticated at all or authenticated
>   incorrectly–but please reauthenticate and try again.” To help you out,
>   it will always include a WWW-Authenticate header that describes how to
>   authenticate

Use jQuery's `beforeSend` callback to add an HTTP header with the authentication information

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you meet the conditions highlighted in [this SO answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29082416/4963159)

Also based on [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221330/4963159) you may want to check that the headers returned from your backend are the same whether you request it from the browser or from an AJAX call.

Comment: The headers are the same, I always pass back `WWW-authenticate` regardless of the type of request when not authenticating successfully.

I have full control over the server in this situation, so I can return additional headers if necessary.

Comment: I see then I am not sure what the issue is, I have seen that working before with pouchDB / couchDB, I can put together a small example

Comment: can you create a small example on plunkr perhaps and I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

you could just trigger a redirect when you check for the 401 condition:

```
window.location = "https://example.com"
```